# Explode an Array in Athena

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena, presto

I have a simple table in athena, it has an array of events. I want to write a simple select statement so that each event in array becomes a row.

I tried explode, transform, but no luck. I have successfully done it in Spark and Hive. But this Athena is tricking me. Please advise

```
DROP TABLE bi_data_lake.royalty_v4;
CREATE external TABLE bi_data_lake.royalty_v4 (
   KAFKA_ID string,
   KAFKA_TS string,
   deviceUser struct< deviceName:string, devicePlatform:string >,
   consumeReportingEvents array<
                                struct<
                                        consumeEvent: string,
                                        consumeEventAction: string,
                                        entryDateTime: string
                                      >
                               >
   )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://XXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Query which is not working

```
select kafka_id, kafka_ts,deviceuser, 
transform( consumereportingevents, consumereportingevent -> consumereportingevent.consumeevent) as cre
from bi_data_lake.royalty_v4 
where kafka_id = 'events-consumption-0-490565';
```

> Not supported
>   lateral view explode(consumereportingevents) as consumereportingevent

**Answer to question it to use unnset**

Found the answer for my question

```
WITH samples AS (
 select kafka_id, kafka_ts,deviceuser, consumereportingevent, consumereportingeventPos
 from bi_data_lake.royalty_v4 
 cross join unnest(consumereportingevents)  WITH ORDINALITY AS T (consumereportingevent, consumereportingeventPos)
 where kafka_id = 'events-consumption-0-490565' or kafka_id = 'events-consumption-0-490566'
)
SELECT * FROM samples
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: The documentation explains how to do this at the bottom of this page: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html

Comment: can you please post sample data and some sample output you are expecting from your query?

Comment: answer to question is to use UNNEST. Updated the question

Answer (score 5):

Flatten ('explode') nested arrays in AWS Athena with `UNNEST`.

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT
    'engineering' as department,
    ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally'] as users
)
SELECT department, names FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(users) as t(names)
```

Reference: [Flattening Nested Arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html)

Comment: @mindatsleep this question is already self answered